# Why the values are NULL if I join the CSV table to a point shapefile

Tags: qgis, csv, attribute-joins

So my problem is all values are NULL if I join my CSV table to a point shapefile, why? (QGIS)

I tried so many things but I cannot find and handle the problem. I have customer names in the CSV, account numbers as well, digits and letters.

OK, I put a screenshot here, that is maybe better to see what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site Juli.  You will likely need to include (as an edit to this post) more information including screenshots and a description of the steps that you took in order to get a good answer.  Please see these links to get you started here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour.

Comment: Do both your csv file and your point shapefile have a common attribute that you are joining?

Comment: yes it looks like this 'D00 045' in both columns. this are account numbers

Comment: Or is there somebody who knows which kombination can I use in the field-calculator to delete the space in the number like this 'D00 0054' ??? that would be also interesting

Comment: Could you also include the exact steps that you used to do the joins?

Comment: So now I got it. I tried something else. I wanted to remove the space out of the numbers which are these ID to join the csv.

I could delete the space with the field-calculator, the funnction for that is replace("text",' ','') so and then the space was deleted. then I joined the csv and dadada it works. the values are all there, not NULL anymore.

Thank you very much all of you for your help!!!keep it up

Answer (score 1):

So now I got it.
I tried something else. I wanted to remove the space out of the numbers which are these ID to join the csv.

I could delete the space with the field-calculator, the funnction for that is replace("text",' ','') 
so and then the space was deleted. then I joined the csv and dadada it works. the values are all there, not NULL anymore.

Thank you very much all of you for your help!!!keep it up